# Filter logcat by selected application *and* add custom filter in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I hate "your app is chatty" - messages, so i wrote a custom filter for them: [image]

This works as expected, but i'd like to enhance it:

Currently, the filter shows logs of all of my appstarts.
I'd like it to only show logs of my current appstart (which is the same as the default filter "show only selected application" does)

I suspect this is possible by filtering the PID, but i don't know how.
(Android Studio hints, that there is code-completion enabled in the PID field)

Answer (score 1):

Locat entries that originate from an app without debug information, only have `?` as package name. Since all system apps don't contain any debug information (AFAIK), messages from the system and most apps can be filtered by typing the following regex into the *Package Name* field:

```
^(?!(\?))
```

This might not be perfect, since you might have other apps with debug information, which could still pollute your log, but for me it's enough.